# php mysql connect fails even though shell client succeeds

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have a weird problem.

I'm trying to connect from a linux host to a remote MySQL server on a Windows host.

If I try to connect from shell using the mysql client it works perfectly.

```
#mysql -h 192.168.x.x -u MyUser -pMyPassword
```

I've also tried connecting from a simple python script and it works as well.

But if I try to connect from a php script it fails with a "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.x.x' (13)" error.

```
mysql_connect ('192.168.x.x', 'MyUser', 'MyPassword');
```

the remote server is running 5.0.41-community-nt on Windows (no info about the OS version)
the client machine is running CentOS 6.2 and is itself equipped with a MySQL 5.1.61 server.
The PHP MySQL module is using the sampe API version 5.1.61

The problem MUST be inside PHP as the connection is successful from the shell client (and even from a python script) but I don't have a clue.

Any help will be higly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078205/php-cant-connect-to-mysql-with-error-13-but-command-line-can

Answer (score 1):

Use the simple PHP way to connect MySQL:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('192.168.x.x', 'MyUser', 'MyPassword');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Please, show us the full code.

Comment: I posted the minimum amount of code able to reproduce the problem. Which was just the same as yours, but with many debug rows and fine printing instructions. Anyway the issue is solved. The problem was in connections opened inside httpd, which SELinux forbids by default.