# Error connecting to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

Tags: mysql, sockets, directadmin

I m using Directadmin; 
It has been while that I m getting this error (knowing that mysqld is running):

Error connecting to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)

would you please indicate me what is exactly the issue ( meaning of the "(13)" ) ,
and possible solution,
thanks.

Comment: check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078205/php-cant-connect-to-mysql-with-error-13-but-command-line-can

and here: http://serverfault.com/questions/503489/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-13-using-php-function

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to update following line in your my.cnf file and try to restart your MySQL services.

`socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`