# Cannot connect Wordpress to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, apache, phpmyadmin

Doing some local website work to learn Wordpress theme development.

Tried to set up Wordpress through the prompts, also tried it by manually entering information in the wp-config.php file, neither would work. Still cannot connect to the database, the setup-config.php page returns "Error establishing a database connection". I've double, triple, and quadruple checked the login credentials (database name, username, password etc.), they are complete and correct. Deleted wp-config.php and tried again through the web page, same result.

MySQL is definitely running, the Mac System Preferences panel says so, and I can login and run SQL queries at the command line, although I have to do that as root. Should I be running MySQL as root?

This problem exists with Wordpress and also with an instance of phpMyAdmin that I've also installed, so I don't think it's anything to do with the PHP code as such, it smells more like a permissions thing. For what it's worth, I've edited my httpd.conf file to get Wordpress on port 80 and phpMyAdmin on 8081. Apache is serving those sites up as it should and PHP is running, it's just getting either site to connect to the database that's the problem.

System information:

Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

PHP Version 5.4.30

MySQL version:
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45, for apple-darwin9.2.0 (i686) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Make sure you set host : localhost and password : Blank when install wordpress in localhost.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was as simple as changing the DB_HOST so it was using the correct host and port in **wp-config.php**:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.01:3306');
```

Comment: This worked for me. I wasn't expecting it to, but thankfully it was the first thing I tried.

Comment: I could connect to the database via terminal and it was driving me crazy! This saved me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on this stackoverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4078205/4384593).

By default, Apache cannot send requests to a remote MySQL server. It should be enabled.

On CentOS 6 the solution is the command:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your phpinfo(); to see if MySQL extension for php is installed.

Comment: I think so.  Under 'Configure Command' it says (among other things): 

 '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--without-pear' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-readline=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--with-snmp=/usr' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--with-tidy' '--enable-wddx' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr'

Comment: Does phpinfo show its enabled though? There should be a table saying MySQL Enabled. Sometimes there may be an error loading the module or it could have been disabled I the configuration file somewhere. I suggest taking a look at mampstack if you just want something up and running.

Comment: Ah, okay.

Under mysql it says:
Active Persistent Links | 0
Active Links | 0
Client API version | mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $

Does this mean it's enabled?

Comment: I run php -m at the command line and I get this, which makes me think it is enabled: mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql

Comment: yes it is linked... If it says enabled in phppinfo it is probably enabled... One thing to do is to post your php configuration

Comment: Actually, I've changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and now it works. Which is odd because my /etc/hosts file maps 127.0.0.1 to localhost. A friend of mine has given me a link to another post on Stack Overflow that explains what's going on in that situation, I'll post it up in the morning.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note that PHP as run through the command line and PHP as run through your web browser may be operating with different configuration files. Just because something is enabled at the command line interface does not guarantee that it is also enabled for the web version.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue and it turned out that the authentication type used by MYSQL was not supported.

To verify this, add

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true)
```

in the wp-config.php and re-run the installation. You will see an entry indicating if that's the case.

If the issue is confirmed to the authentication method, try

```
mysql> CREATE USER ‘username’@‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY ‘password’;
```

after logging in to mysql console.