# RHEL unable to connect MySQL database via PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, rhel

I have been trying to find the issue but failed to spot so far in my `RHEL Server 7.5(Maipo)`. I have a remote database instance (RDS instance) on my AWS. Which is in the same public subnet. And can be accessed and connected if I run `mysql -h <remote-db-hostname> -u <username> -p` in my above mentioned instance terminal.

Moreover, if I try to run `sudo telnet <remote-db-hostname> 3306` it returns success, and says: "*connected to xxxx.xxx. host*".

**Installed `yum` packages:**

- `php-mysql.x86_64`       *(5.4.16-45.el7)*
- `mariadb.x86_64`          *(1:5.5.56-2.el7)*
- `mariadb-libs.x86_64`        *(1:5.5.56-2.el7)*
- `httpd.x86_64`            *(2.4.6-80.el7_5.1)*
- `httpd-tools.x86_64`         *(2.4.6-80.el7_5.1)*

**PHP connection doesn't work**

But when I try to connect to connect via simple PHP code, it doesn't work. It says: 
*Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.*
or
*Could not connect host: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (13)*

I have tried to use host name both ways, with Port and without Port but no success.

*Test Connection File:*

```
$host = 'remote-db-hostname:3306';  // ofcourse using correct hostname
$user = 'xxxxx';
$pswd = 'xxxxx';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect host: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('my-db-name', $link) or die('could not connect to the specified database');

mysql_close($link);
```

*Here is my `/etc/my.cnf` file:*

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Note: There are two files in `/etc/my.cnf.d`; 1) `client.cnf` 2) `mysql-clients.cnf`

*client.cnf*

```
# These two groups are read by the client library
# Use it for options that affect all clients, but not the server

[client]

# This group is not read by mysql client library,
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# use it for MariaDB-only client options
[client-mariadb]
```

*mysql-clients.cnf*

```
# These groups are read by MariaDB command-line tools
# Use it for options that affect only one utility
#
[mysql]
[mysql_upgrade]
[mysqladmin]
[mysqlbinlog]
[mysqlcheck]
[mysqldump]
[mysqlimport]
[mysqlshow]
[mysqlslap]
```

*/etc/selinux/config*:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: What config files are included from `/etc/my.cnf.d`?

Comment: There are two files in it, have specified those names in my updated question. I have been struggling with this since yesterday. But no luck.

Comment: The names don't really matter, the content of course does.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078205/php-cant-connect-to-mysql-with-error-13-but-command-line-can

Comment: Due to SE linux apache user is not able to connect to remote db. Try once after disabling SE Linux. Also go through this url https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-booleans-configuring_booleans

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but [`mysql_connect()` is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), and you should not use it.  Use [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) instead.

Comment: Really appreciate the quick assistance. You saved my day. Run this `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1` and it worked like a charm. One last clarification; isn't it better to use `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on` instead? So we are only allowing to connect to DB and not any other way to any other machine?

Comment: =1 does mean On - Enable.  And you KNOW it works.  The link by SynapseIndia indicate you should use space bar On - obviously more than one way is possible.